# How could I mark a git branch as deprecated

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, deprecated

Is there a way I can mark one of my git branches as deprecated so if anyone tries to push to it (or ideally even if someone commits into it)?
I want git to show a warning saying that the branch is deprecated and should not be used.
I need this for a particular branch only, not for entire repo.

Would you please advise how I could do so?

Comment: You could rename the branch to include “deprecated” in the name.

Comment: Yes, but that's definitely what I wouldn't want to do

Comment: May I ask why? Renaming branches isn’t really a problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me an elegant way to do things. :) Looks mostly as a workaround.

Comment: I don't think renaming a branch falls under the category of elegant or non-elegant...it's just a very easy way to show people that a branch is deprecated.

Comment: Adding a hook is extra security, but renaming the branch is probably also prudent.

Comment: What do you think about create a tag and delete de branch?

Comment: I have a similar question, which doesn't involve the dev process. In https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now the "master" branch was the default branch but I've changed things and it's not anymore, it's kept to avoid external links to be broken, but it will grow outdated. i've put a deprecation notice on the branch README, but would ideally like to "mark" it as deprecated without breaking external links. Tag could be a solution, but I believe it'd change the URL and thus break external links anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If the branch is deprecated and people are still trying to push to it, it sounds like there's some kind of breakdown in your dev process. That being said, it sounds like you can address this using a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

One option is to use a client side hook such as a [`pre-commit` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks) that would be run on the dev's local machine when they tried to commit. The idea is that you check if the branch they're committing onto matches (using regex) this or any other deprecated branches. If so, return a non-zero exit status to block the commit.

Alternatively, if you wanted to prevent someone from pushing an update to the branch on the remote repo, you could use an [`update` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks).

To see examples of these hooks, check the `.git/hooks` directory on any repo (the example hook will be `hook-name.example`).

Comment: I don't see any breakdowns here. People just got used to the old branch and once we change the process I want to add some protection to not let someone push to old branch just by old habit. As for precommit hook - I think that's worth looking into. Thanks!